# Runtime exception: Unable to resume activity - native typeface cannot be made

Tags: android

I am getting this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

I am posted the relevant code below and pointed out the error line.

**Stacktrace:**

```
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791): Process: com.qrme.quranmadeeasy, PID: 1791
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.qrme.quranmadeeasy/com.qrme.quranmadeeasy.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2774)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2238)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at com.qrme.quranmadeeasy.SettingsActivity.initialize(SettingsActivity.java:118)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at com.qrme.quranmadeeasy.SettingsActivity.onResume(SettingsActivity.java:104)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2764)
01-27 06:57:39.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1791):     ... 12 more
```

**SettingsActivity.java:**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

  }
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    initialize();  -->104th line
    onclick();
}

    public void initialize() {

        txtGeneral=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewGeneral);
        txtplay=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewContinuousPlay);
        txtplatdes=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewContinousplay_des);
        txtrepeat=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewRepeat);
        txtrepeatdes=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewCount_des);
        txtlanguage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewLanguage);
        txtlanguagedes=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewLanguage_des);

        Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "UthmanicHafs.ttf"); --->118th line

        txtplatdes.setTypeface(type);
        txtrepeatdes.setTypeface(type);
        txtlanguagedes.setTypeface(type);

        type=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "UthmanicHafs.ttf");
        txtGeneral.setTypeface(type);
        txtplay.setTypeface(type);
        txtrepeat.setTypeface(type);
        txtlanguage.setTypeface(type);

}
}
```

Comment: try `Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(), "UthmanicHaf.ttf");`

Comment: @MD This one solved my runtime error.please post your answer with explanation.But finally I am getting an error at `UserProfile in doInBackground `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(), "UthmanicHaf.ttf");
```

You can also access `Asset` by using `getBaseContext().getAssets()`